# привязка данных wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml

Есть класс  Person

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Images { get; set; }

    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Есть xml файл UsersList

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<users>
  <user name="Bill Gates">
    <images>https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558109954561679360/j1f9DiJi.jpeg</images>
    <age>48</age>
  </user>
  <user name="Larry Page">
    <images>http://www.siliconbeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/page.jpg</images>
    <age>42</age>
  </user>
</users>
```

XAML файл

```
<ListBox  x:Name="ListBox" Margin="36,10,273,0" >
            <ListBox.DataContext>
                <user:Person/>
            </ListBox.DataContext>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding Images}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

code-behind

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load();
        }
    public void Load()
        {
            Person user = new Person();
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load("UsersList");

            XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

            foreach (XmlNode xnode in xRoot)
            {


                if (xnode.Attributes.Count > 0)
                {
                    XmlNode attr = xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name");
                    if (attr != null)
                        user.Name = attr.Value;

                }

                foreach (XmlNode childnode in xnode.ChildNodes)
                {

                    if (childnode.Name == "images")
                    {
                        user.Images = childnode.InnerText;

                    }

                    if (childnode.Name == "age")
                    {
                        user.Age = childnode.InnerText;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

У меня такой вопрос как правильно привязать файл данные к XAML? 
Я понимаю что можно сделать:

```
Person user1 = new Person { Name = "Bill Gates", Age = 48, Images = "" };
Person user2 = new Person { Name = "Larry Page", Age = 42, Images = "" };
List<Person> users = new List<Person> { user1, user2 };
```

и все круто будет, но если список будет 100 человек, не вариант вручную вносить. Да и редактировать и удалять проблематично.

Comment: А что мешает в функции Load заполнять список List<Person> users? Да и вообще странный метод Load Для Person user = new Person(); зачем то переприсваиваются значения в цикле  foreach (XmlNode xnode in xRoot) вы же его нигде не используете, почему бы не добавлять его в список users в конце внешнего цикла

Comment: используйте сериализатор, загрузите файл и в контексте данных просто сделайте свойство которое будет представлять собой список пользователей.

Comment: @user2455111 дело в том что лиц порядка 100 штук  и нужно предвидеть изменения круга лиц. как я понял с ваших слов, чтобы отредактировать или добавить человека мне придется редактировать код-бихайнд  и компилировать программу.

Comment: @user2455111 Все,  разобрался о чем вы писали: ListBox.itemsSource = users;